# Runnning Hadoop map-reduce job remotely causes EOFException?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, remote-access, cloudera

I have written a Hadoop map-reduce program and now I want to test it on [Cloadera Hadoop distribution](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH+Downloads) that is running on the same computer in [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Here is how do I submit that map-reduce job:

```
public class AvgCounter extends Configured implements Tool{

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job mrJob = Job.getInstance(new Cluster(getConf()), getConf()); 
        mrJob.setJobName("Average count");

        mrJob.setJarByClass(AvgCounter.class);
        mrJob.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        mrJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        mrJob.setMapperClass(AvgCounterMap.class);
        mrJob.setCombinerClass(AvgCounterReduce.class);
        mrJob.setReducerClass(AvgCounterReduce.class);
        mrJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        mrJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(mrJob, new Path("/user/test/testdata.csv"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(mrJob, new Path("/user/test/result.txt"));
        mrJob.setWorkingDirectory(new Path("/tmp"));
        return mrJob.waitForCompletion(true)? 1: 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.5.50:9000");
        conf.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "192.168.5.50:9001");
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(conf, new AvgCounter(), args));
    }
}
```

`AvgCounterMap` has empty `map` method that does nothing as well as `AvgCounterReduce` has empty `reduce` method that does nothing. When I try to run the main method I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to /192.168.5.50:9001 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:198)
    at $Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.createRPCProxy(Cluster.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.createClient(Cluster.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:74)
    at eu.xxx.mapred.AvgCounter.run(AvgCounter.java:22)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:69)
    at eu.xxx.mapred.AvgCounter.main(AvgCounter.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:698)
```

The virtual Cloudera machine that runs Hadoop has following in file `/etc/hadoop/conf/core.site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://192.168.5.50:9000</value>
</property>
```

and in the file `/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred.site.xml` there is

```
<property>
     <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
     <value>192.168.5.50:9001</value>
</property>
```

I have also checked checked connection to virtual machine by writing `92.168.5.50:50030` to my web browser and I got Hadoop Map/Reduce administration as expected. So what is causeing that exception and how do I get rid of it?

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: I have also tried to kill iptables on Cloudera machine with no result.

Comment: can you ping both those ips from the tasktracker?

Comment: Are you mixing libraries (client side using apache hadoop, server side is cloudera hadoop?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that client was using different version of Hadoop API (0.23.0) then the Hadoop instalation.